# How do I change the name of my app on my KMM project with Android Studio?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I created a project and by default it runs and shows the `package name/bundle id` of my project, is there a way to change it with Android Studio?

I've changed the icon on AppIcon.appiconset/res folders, but I don't know how to change the name of my app. On Android its just by creating the `string.xml` and adding the reference on my `AndroidManifest.xml` res, but on iOS is my problem. btw I need to do it just by using Android Studio.

Comment: KMM just generates a framework that's used by iOS app, it doesn't have control over such things. same as for android you have to do it in app module, not in `shared` one - you have to open project in Xcode and update iOS app name there. you may be able to setup sharing somehow, but it won't be trivial and will require deep iOS knowledge

Comment: yes that's what I supposed, I thought It was going to be easy with Android Studio. anyway I've done with xcode. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Config.xcconfig in Android Studio and change the APP_NAM field. Then close android studio and run ./cleanup.sh in your terminal. You should see the the new name when you build the app on iOS.

Comment: How to build the Android app on iOS?